# Exception initialization error javacv

Tags: android, javacv

I am using javacv for my project, 
in my project i want to use opencv_highui.cvLoadImage function

I have added javacv.jar,javacpp.jar in libs folder,and extract all so files 
in libs/armebi-v7a folder

but when i run my project it gives me error of exceptionintialization error 
is there any other steps to follow for opencv

Please give me some suggestion

here is me code

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {



            try {
                cvLoadImage("mnt/sdcard/make_machine_example1.png");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

![][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C19pE.png
i have also attached my project structure , Please suggest me

Here is the stack trace

```
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.example.demoproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:  1418 cannot locate '_ZSt10unexpectedv'...
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:701)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:578)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:79)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     ... 15 more
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_static: findLibrary returned null
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:701)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:569)
    11-21 14:49:47.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2250):     ... 17 more

after adding that jars from build path i have following exception 

11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.example.demoproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Arrays.copyOf
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.findLibrary(Loader.java:646)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:568)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:79)
11-21 15:02:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    ... 14 more
```

Do you have any idea about it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091986/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-in-javacv).
You maybe need to add the .so files in the armeabi folder too, not only armeabi-v7a. [I had that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045041/exceptionininitializererror-in-stitcher-with-javacv-for-android) but in the opposite way and I solved doing it.

By the way, how do you use the function? Remember that you have to put the whole name (also with the directories) if you are not working with pictures in the same folder. I would put it just in case even in that case.

I do it like this and it works:

```
cvLoadImage("/storage/sdcard0/Download/testpicture.JPG");
```

Comment: yes I have tried this but got same exception intialization error with I got following error,11-21 14:09:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(23824): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_static: findLibrary returned null,11-21 14:09:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(23824): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]: 1418 cannot locate '_ZSt10unexpectedv'..., Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Ok, I have seen your pictures, both .jar should't appear there, at least they are not there for me after the whole process. I think you miss these steps (at the beginning you have the .jar exactly where they are now): 1. Navigate to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...". 2.Select both javacpp.jar and javacv.jar from the newly created "libs" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the  `*.so` files DIRECTLY inside your projects `libs/armeabi` directory. DO NOT put them inside any other sub-directories such as: `libs/armeabi/com/googlecode/...` etc